# Align left border of geom_col column with data anchor

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some timestamped data with ggplot2 and R. Here is a minimal and reproducible example of my current work

> ```
> library(lubridate)
> library(ggplot2)
>
> sample_size <- 100
>
> start_date = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00")
> end_date = as.POSIXct("2020-01-02 00:00")
>
> timestamps <- as.POSIXct(sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by=60), sample_size))
> amount <- rpois(sample_size, 5)
>
> df <- data.frame(timestamps=timestamps, amount=amount)
>
> df$hour_group <- floor_date(df$timestamps, unit="1 hour")
> ggplot(df, aes(x=hour_group, y=amount)) + geom_col()
> ```

**Explanation:** First a sample dataframe with the column *timestamp* and *amount* is created. The timestamps are uniformly selected between the `start_date` and `end_date`. I'd like to plot the `amount` variable for each hour of the day. Therefore another column `hour_group` is created and filled with the hour of each timestamp.

Plotting this data yields the following graph:

[image]

The columns look alright, but since the first column for example represents the sum of the `amount` with timestamps between `00:00` and `01:00` I'd like the column to fill exactly this space (not `23:30` to `00:30` as in the current plot). Therefore I want to align the left border of each column with the anchor point (in the example `00:00`) and not center the column at this point. How can this be achieved?

**My approach:** One way I can think is to created another column with the shifted anchor points. In the example a 30minute shift is necessary.

> ```
> df$hour_group_shifted <- df$hour_group + 60*30
> ```

The new plot creates the expected result

[image]

I'm still wondering if there may be a simpler way to achieve this directly with a ggplot setting without the extra column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position_nudge`.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour_group, y=amount)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_nudge(60*30))
```

Comment: This does work. Thank you. I'll not accept it now to possible attract another answer, but this is enough for me.

Comment: I was just using `+ scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H"))` in the graph above, but it then the data is `23 ... 5 ... 11 ... etc.`. Do you have an idea why it doesn't go to `0 ... 6 ... 12 ...`?

Comment: Using my example above, I get `0 ... 6 ... 12` with `scale_x_datetime` as you specified, so not sure why it isn't the same for you.

Comment: I just cam across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348329/date-breaks-scales-shifts-date-scale-in-ggplot) post. It may have to do with timezones (I'm from Germany).

Comment: Using `labels = date_format("%H", tz=Sys.timezone())` works.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`ggplot2 3.4.0`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#new-features-3-4-0), you can use `just = 0` to align your columns as needed:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour_group, y=amount)) + 
  geom_col(just = 0)
```

[image]